# Replacing Android's Launcher App before compilation

Tags: android

I want to have my own Launcher Application for Android

in other words , I want my own Application to run directly after booting , instead of the Launcher app 
as I am not running Android on a Mobile phone , and I don't want Android's Home GUI

also I want to change the app in the source code , before compilation

I have tried to Simply replace files under "/packages/apps/Launcher" with my HelloWorld App
then running this command "mmm packages/apps/Launcher"
but It didn't work

So any book/tutorial/advice that covers this point ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no books on the market that cover Android internals such as what you are trying to do, at least as of the time of this comment. It'd be a welcome addition to the available roster of books if anyone wants to write it. :-)

Comment: Have you looked into what home screen replacement apps do?  Perhaps that could lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android was designed to be so modular that it supports what we want without any tweaks !! maybe little tweaks in your program only

Android doesn't go for a specific Launcher app in predefined location and run itin fact you can have multiple Home Screen installed .. each App identifies itself somewhere in it's code that it is a Home App Then Android in booting decides which home App to load
Demo  @ http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html , which is included in the SDK samples too

Answer (score 0):

This should not present any great difficulty to you, Android has provisions for this and there are many third party launchers available.  There is an example at developer.android.com that will show you exactly how to implement and deploy your home screen replacement app:  [Home - Home | Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html)